# Is this a discovery or something known? "You find any Integer solution for pythagorean quadruples, pythagorean quintuple. using quaternions √

Tags: quaternions

If you take a quaternion number lets call it Q (Q=a+bi+cj)) Q² definitely generate a pythagorean quadruple and Q=a+bi+cj+dk will definitely generate pythagorean quintuple

ex: Q=1+1i+1j+k, Q² = (-2)+2i+2j+2k, and 2²+2²+2²+2²=16 and 16 is 4² and this is true for any integers a,b,c,d

proof 1: Q = a+bi+cj+dk, Q² = (a+bi+cj+dk)(a+bi+cj+dk)= (a² - b² - c² - d²) + 2abi + 2acj + 2adk
remove all the complex numbers so it'll be (a² - b² - c² - d²) + 2ab + 2ac + 2ad
square every part so it'll be (a² - b² - c² - d²)² + (2ab)² + (2ac)² + (2ad)²
and if you factor it it'll be (a²+b²+c²+d²) and there is it 4 squared numbers that equal another square

Comment: Please define pythagorean $n$-tuple, and state precisely the result you mean.

Comment: Yes, this is all well-known. @Kimball I think it's pretty clear what the OP means, though their English is poor.

Comment: @runway44 It's not clear to me--e.g., if $Q$ satisfies $d=0$ in their notation, $Q^2$ typically does not, so I'm not sure whether what they want to say in this case is true.